# CoreData errors for simple adding to database

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, input

Edit: The error messages that I am trying to figure out are on the right side of the code listed as comments!!!

Xcode keeps trying to suggest alternatives and refusing to let me build. The 3 are listed in comment tags on the right side of the code. What do they mean? I am very new to using core data and really hoping to see what I am doing wrong, just using username as an example (as I know I shouldn't be doing so)!

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *cxt = [self managedObjectContext];       //instance method managedObjectContext not found
    NSManagedObject *newContacts = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:cxt];
    [newContacts setValue:self.username.text forKey:@"username"];          //insert NSManagedObjectModel instead of NSManagedObject...claims that it is undeclared?
    username.text = @"";

    NSManagedObject *newContacts = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:cxt];     //trying to replace NSEntityDescription with KSecAttrDescription...claims that it is undeclared      
    [newContacts setValue:self.password.text forKey:@"password"];
    password.text = @"";

    NSError *err;
    if (![cxt save:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", [err localizedDescription]);      //Instance Method -save not found
    }           

}
```

Comment: The first error says that `managedObjectContext` isn't defined as a method (or property) within whatever class contains this code.  Do you have such a definition somewhere?  (**Some** of the other problems probably follow from that one, so I'd suggest fixing it first.)

Comment: Solved it! However, it was from a previous answer for this question who removed them self, so I'm giving the credit to that unknown person. If anybody has this error in the future, click on you core data.xcdatamoldeld, then click on the Editor section on your menu bar (of your desktop), then click set NSManagedObject Subclass and add them. It should work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! However, it was from a previous answer for this question who removed them self, so I'm giving the credit to that unknown person. If anybody has this error in the future, click on you core data.xcdatamoldeld, then click on the Editor section on your menu bar (of your desktop), then click set NSManagedObject Subclass and add them. It should work then.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData code looks good, but you are using `NSManagedObject *newContacts` twice, just use another variable name or remove  `NSManagedObject *` for the second object.

Also i would recommend you to make classes for your objects to have a direct access to variables instead of `[obj setValue:value forKey:@"key"];`

And of course it would be nice to see the error output.

Comment: Ummm...I don't understand. What do you mean about classes for my objects? Can you give an example. Oh, and error output is in the right hand side as comments in the code so that people can tell where in the code it is

Comment: Though, creating two Contacts, one with only a username and the other with only a password, is suspicious.

Comment: This is a very nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) about how to use `CoreData`, please search for `Auto Generating Model Files` there, this is what i mean by classes for your objects (sorry for this)