# Errors in Xcode Coredata about using wrong methods?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I keep getting error messages (which all 3 are listed as comments on the side of the code so that you know where they are) while trying to utilize CoreData. I can't find these errors online for some reason. I am very new to CoreData and very interested to find out what I am doing wrong. And if anybody is wondering, I had an earlier version of this script, but it changed too much (see [CoreData errors for simple adding to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922686/coredata-errors-for-simple-adding-to-database))

```
@synthesize username, password;

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
    AppayAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];    

    NSManagedObject *newContact;      //Unknown type, did you mean NSManagedObjectModel?

    newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];      //Use of undeclared identifier NSEntityDescription. Did you mean kSecAttrDescription?

    [newContact setValue:name.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newContact setValue:address.text forKey:@"address"];

    name.text = @"";
    address.text = @"";

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];    //instance method -save not found
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Managed Object Class for each entity. Also to get the Appdelegate I don't see that you are including the header file nor do I see the header file for the managed object class. These are both needed for your application to be able to access the context and the Managed Objects.

Comment: Thanks, but just solved it! If anybody has this error in the future, click on you core data.xcdatamoldeld, then click on the Editor section on your menu bar (of your desktop), then click set NSManagedObject Subclass and add them. It should work then...I think you gave the right method in your response, so I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0):

Using the file inspector, select the entity you are using and use the entity inspector, you need to change the entity class. If you leave it to NSManagedObject (default value), you will need to use setValue:forKey: to assign values to your custom entity.'

Edit: Something related to this: Do not use common names for your custom entity classes. You might find yourself with runtime errors when using names  (such as "Contact") which are present in the objective-c runtime. Use your project prefix when creating subclasses, even for entity classes.

Comment: Would that runtime error possibly be a permeant black screen on startup instead of my storyboard screen (black screen even past the loading screen)

Comment: No specifically. It would be random glitches and crashes. You will also receive a warning saying that the classes are conflicting.